# How to update the LED on a TI board and report to the server every second via UART

Tags: c, embedded

I am modifying a code in embedded C language and trying to make it to where it checks buttons every 200ms, checks the temperature every 500ms, and update the LED and report to the server every second. My code appears to be complete but when I run it, nothing outputs to the console, and my LED light neither turns off or on when I press either buttons on the side of the TI board. Is there something wrong with my nested while loop? Here is my code:

```
/*
 *  ======== gpiointerrupt.c ========
 */
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

/* Driver Header files */
#include <ti/drivers/GPIO.h>
#include <ti/drivers/I2C.h>
#include <ti/drivers/UART.h>

/* Driver configuration */
#include "ti_drivers_config.h"

/* Driver timer */
#include <ti/drivers/Timer.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

#define NUMBER_OF_TASKS 3
#define GLOBAL_PERIOD 100 //milliseconds

#define DISPLAY(x) UART_write(uart, &output, x);
// UART Global Variables
char output[64];
int bytesToSend;
// Driver Handles - Global variables
UART_Handle uart;

// Init variables
int buttonCheckTime = 0;
int tempCheckTime = 0;
int displayCheckTime = 0;
int buttonCheckPeriod = 200;
int tempCheckPeriod = 500;
int displayCheckPeriod = 1000;
int setpoint = 25;
int heat = 0;
int seconds = 0;
int temperature = 0;
int firstButtonWasPressed = FALSE; // It is initally false that the button was pressed
int secondButtonWasPressed = FALSE; // It is initally false that the button was pressed
int global_period = GLOBAL_PERIOD; // Global period to be used initTimer()

void initUART(void)
{
    UART_Params uartParams;
// Init the driver
    UART_init();
// Configure the driver
    UART_Params_init(&uartParams);
    uartParams.writeDataMode = UART_DATA_BINARY;
    uartParams.readDataMode = UART_DATA_BINARY;
    uartParams.readReturnMode = UART_RETURN_FULL;
    uartParams.baudRate = 115200;
// Open the driver
    uart = UART_open(CONFIG_UART_0, &uartParams);
    if (uart == NULL)
    {
        /* UART_open() failed */
        while (1)
            ;
    }
}

// I2C Global Variables
static const struct
{
    uint8_t address;
    uint8_t resultReg;
    char *id;
} sensors[3] = { { 0x48, 0x0000, "11X" }, { 0x49, 0x0000, "116" }, { 0x41,
                                                                     0x0001,
                                                                     "006" } };
uint8_t txBuffer[1];
uint8_t rxBuffer[2];
I2C_Transaction i2cTransaction;
// Driver Handles - Global variables
I2C_Handle i2c;

// Initialize the I2C peripheral
// Make sure you call initUART() before calling this function.
void initI2C(void)
{
    int8_t i, found;
    I2C_Params i2cParams;
    DISPLAY(snprintf(output, 64, "Initializing I2C Driver - "))
// Init the driver
    I2C_init();
// Configure the driver
    I2C_Params_init(&i2cParams);
    i2cParams.bitRate = I2C_400kHz;
// Open the driver
    i2c = I2C_open(CONFIG_I2C_0, &i2cParams);
    if (i2c == NULL)
    {
        DISPLAY(snprintf(output, 64, "Failed\n\r"))
        while (1)
            ;
    }
    DISPLAY(snprintf(output, 32, "Passed\n\r"))
// Boards were shipped with different sensors.
// Welcome to the world of embedded systems.
// Try to determine which sensor we have.
// Scan through the possible sensor addresses
    /* Common I2C transaction setup */
    i2cTransaction.writeBuf = txBuffer;
    i2cTransaction.writeCount = 1;
    i2cTransaction.readBuf = rxBuffer;
    i2cTransaction.readCount = 0;
    found = false;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        i2cTransaction.slaveAddress = sensors[i].address;
        txBuffer[0] = sensors[i].resultReg;
        DISPLAY(snprintf(output, 64, "Is this %s? ", sensors[i].id))
        if (I2C_transfer(i2c, &i2cTransaction))
        {
            DISPLAY(snprintf(output, 64, "Found\n\r"))
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        DISPLAY(snprintf(output, 64, "No\n\r"))
    }
    if (found)
    {
        DISPLAY(snprintf(output, 64, "Detected TMP%s I2C address: %x\n\r",
                         sensors[i].id, i2cTransaction.slaveAddress))
    }
    else
    {
        DISPLAY(snprintf(output, 64,
                         "Temperature sensor not found, contact professor\n\r"))
    }
}
int16_t readTemp(void)
{
    int j;
    int16_t temperature = 0;
    i2cTransaction.readCount = 2;
    if (I2C_transfer(i2c, &i2cTransaction))
    {
        /*
         * Extract degrees C from the received data;
         * see TMP sensor datasheet
         */
        temperature = (rxBuffer[0] << 8) | (rxBuffer[1]);
        temperature *= 0.0078125;
        /*
         * If the MSB is set '1', then we have a 2's complement
         * negative value which needs to be sign extended
         */
        if (rxBuffer[0] & 0x80)
        {
            temperature |= 0xF000;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DISPLAY(snprintf(output, 64, "Error reading temperature sensor (%d)\n\r", i2cTransaction.status))
        DISPLAY(snprintf(output,64, "Please power cycle your board by unplugging USB and plugging back in.\n\r"))
    }
    return temperature;
}

// Driver Handles - Global variables
Timer_Handle timer0;
volatile unsigned char TimerFlag = 0;

// A single task in the task list.
struct task_entry
{
    void (*f)();    // Function to call to perform the task
    int elapsed_time;   // Amount of time since last triggered
    int period;     // Period of the task in ms
    char triggered; // Whether or not the task was triggered
};

// Forward declaration
void task_one();
void task_two();
void task_three();

void task_one()
{
    // Processing for task_one takes place
    /* Every 200ms, check button presses */
    if (buttonCheckTime >= buttonCheckPeriod) // Button check time equals or exceeds period
    {
        if (firstButtonWasPressed == TRUE) // Button on one side raises setpoint (thermostat setting) by 1
        {
            setpoint += 1;                               // Increment thermostat
            firstButtonWasPressed = FALSE;              // Reset button to FALSE
        }
        if (secondButtonWasPressed == TRUE) // Button on the other side lowers setpoint (thermostat setting) by 1
        {
            setpoint -= 1;                               // Decrement thermostat
            secondButtonWasPressed = FALSE;             // Reset button to FALSE
        }
    }

}
void task_two()
{
    // Processing for task_two takes place
    if (tempCheckTime >= tempCheckPeriod)   // Temperature check time equals or exceeds period
    {
        temperature = readTemp();
        if (temperature > setpoint) {
            GPIO_write(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_0, CONFIG_GPIO_LED_OFF);
            heat = 0;
        }
        else {
            GPIO_write(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_0, CONFIG_GPIO_LED_ON);
            heat = 1;
        }
    }

}
void task_three()
{
    // Processing for task_three takes place
    if (displayCheckTime == displayCheckPeriod) {
        DISPLAY(snprintf(output, 64, "<%02d,%02d,%d,%04d>\n\r", temperature,
                                setpoint, heat, seconds));
        ++seconds;
    }
}

// The task list
struct task_entry tasks[NUMBER_OF_TASKS] = { { FALSE, &task_one, 500, 500 }, {FALSE, &task_two, 1500, 1500 }, { FALSE, &task_three, 2000, 2000 } };

void timerCallback(Timer_Handle myHandle, int_fast16_t status)
{
    int x = 0;
    // Walk through each task.
        for (x = 0; x < NUMBER_OF_TASKS; x++)
        {
            // Check if task's interval has expire
            if (tasks[x].elapsed_time >= tasks[x].period)
            {
                // Bing! This task's timer is up
                // Set it's flag, and the global flag
                tasks[x].triggered = TRUE;
                TimerFlag = TRUE;
                // Reset the elapsed_time
                tasks[x].elapsed_time = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                tasks[x].elapsed_time += global_period;
            }
        }
}
void initTimer(void)
{
    Timer_Params params;
// Init the driver
    Timer_init();
// Configure the driver
    Timer_Params_init(&params);
    params.period = 1000000;
    params.periodUnits = Timer_PERIOD_US;
    params.timerMode = Timer_CONTINUOUS_CALLBACK;
    params.timerCallback = timerCallback;
// Open the driver
    timer0 = Timer_open(CONFIG_TIMER_0, &params);
    if (timer0 == NULL)
    {
        /* Failed to initialized timer */
        while (1)
        {
        }
    }
    if (Timer_start(timer0) == Timer_STATUS_ERROR)
    {
        /* Failed to start timer */
        while (1)
        {
        }
    }

}

/*
 *  ======== gpioButtonFxn0 ========
 *  Callback function for the GPIO interrupt on CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_0.
 *
 *  Note: GPIO interrupts are cleared prior to invoking callbacks.
 */
void gpioButtonFxn0(uint_least8_t index)
{
    /* Toggle an LED */
    //GPIO_toggle(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_0);
    firstButtonWasPressed = TRUE;  // It is true that the button was pressed
}

/*
 *  ======== gpioButtonFxn1 ========
 *  Callback function for the GPIO interrupt on CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_1.
 *  This may not be used for all boards.
 *
 *  Note: GPIO interrupts are cleared prior to invoking callbacks.
 */
void gpioButtonFxn1(uint_least8_t index)
{
    /* Toggle an LED */
    //GPIO_toggle(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_1);
    secondButtonWasPressed = TRUE;
}

/*
 *  ======== mainThread ========
 */
void* mainThread(void *arg0)
{
    /* Call driver init functions */
        GPIO_init();

        /* Configure the LED and button pins */
        GPIO_setConfig(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_0, GPIO_CFG_OUT_STD | GPIO_CFG_OUT_LOW);
        //GPIO_setConfig(CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_0;
        //GPIO_CFG_IN_PU | GPIO_CFG_IN_INT_FALLING);

        /* Turn on user LED */
        GPIO_write(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_0, CONFIG_GPIO_LED_ON);

        /* Install Button callback */
        GPIO_setCallback(CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_0, gpioButtonFxn0);

        /* Enable interrupts */
        GPIO_enableInt(CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_0);

        /*
         *  If more than one input pin is available for your device, interrupts
         *  will be enabled on CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON1.
         */
        if (CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_0 != CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_1)
        {
            /* Configure BUTTON1 pin */
            GPIO_setConfig(CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_1,
            GPIO_CFG_IN_PU | GPIO_CFG_IN_INT_FALLING);

            /* Install Button callback */
            GPIO_setCallback(CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_1, gpioButtonFxn1);

            /* Enable interrupts */
            GPIO_enableInt(CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_1);
        }

    // Call driver init functions
    initUART(); // The UART must be initialized before calling initI2C()
    initI2C();
    initTimer();

    // Loop Forever
    while (TRUE)
    {
        readTemp();
        // Every 200ms check the button flags
        task_one();
        // Every 500ms read the temperature and update the LED
        task_two();
        // Every second output the following to the UART
        // "<%02d,%02d,%d,%04d>, temperature, setpoint, heat, seconds
        task_three();
        // Wait for task intervals (periods) to elapse
        while (!TimerFlag)
        {
        } // Wait for timer period
        // Process the tasks for which the interval has expired
        int x = 0;
        for (x = 0; x < NUMBER_OF_TASKS; x++)
        {
            if (tasks[x].triggered)
            {
                tasks[x].f();
                // reset
                tasks[x].triggered = FALSE;
            }
        }
        // Reset everything (e.g. flags) and go back to the beginning
        TimerFlag = FALSE;  // Lower flag raised by timer
        ++global_period;
    }

}
```

Comment: A suggestion ... Initialize the UART first (as I think you're doing). Then, have the program output a fixed string (e.g. `hello world` ;-) immediately. That way, you know the UART is working. Note that if the UART init fails, you go into an infinite loop, so you'd get nothing. Also, ensure that the terminal program on your development PC (which is connected to the UART) is configured properly. No UART output could be bad init on _either_ system. Then, you can add debug `printf` statements that output to the UART. This can help you debug the rest of your code.

Comment: After getting UART output from the embedded system to the PC working, you might ensure that the PC can send data to the embedded system. Then, you can implement a "single step" mode (e.g.) The system outputs "STEP1" and waits for a newline from the PC before continuing. Also, is `UART_write` a _blocking_ call (it will ensure that the data is/can be written to the UART)? Or, do you have to loop on it or poll the TxRDY bit before outputting a char?

Comment: With regard to UART init, in particular, what are you doing with the RTS/CTS lines? You may have to configure the systems to assert the lines and/or ignore them.

Comment: What did you find out when you stepped through with your debugger?  If you have no debugger  then you have a big problem and you will have to resort to a lengthy 'simplify task until something works, then build back up'  exercise as commented by the others ((